# Visual Studio 2017: "The dje culture cannot be converted to a CultureInfo object on this computer"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I recently moved a C# WinForms project from one computer to another, both running Visual Studio 2017. When I try and open one of the forms, I get the error:

```
The dje culture cannot be converted to a CultureInfo object on this computer
```

There is an "Ignore and Continue" button, which freezes Visual Studio when I click on it. This is also only occurring on one of the forms and all of the other forms works fine.

The form is called "Rewards" and consists of the files `Rewards.cs`, `Rewards.designer.cs`, `Rewards.dje.resx`, and `Rewards.resx`. If desired, I could upload these files.

What kinds of things would cause this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Rewards.dje.resx` is considered a language resource file. `dje` is not a recognized language identifier (as `en`, `de` etc)

Comment: I changed the `$this.Language` property value to `en` and renamed the file to `Rewards.en.resx` and it works. Any clue why that bad localization would exist to begin with?

Comment: Just look at the history of your project in Git (or whatever source control you are using) and see how it is started… it is unlikely anyone else will be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi pointed out in the comments, the problem was that Visual Studio 2017 looking for a "dje" language, which does not exist. I changed the `$this.Language` value to `en` in the `Rewards.resx` file, and renamed the `Rewards.dje.resx` file to `Rewards.en.resx`, and then it worked.